# How to iteratively add a parameter into a function

Tags: python, numpy, loops, for-loop, reshape

I have an array `results` which is multi-dimensional. Every time when I increase a parameter `n`, there will be more entries created in the array `results` and the array will get larger.

With each increase in `n`, I need to perform the function `reshape()` on the array `results`, such that there will be more parameters added into the `reshape()` function every time `n` increases.

For eg., when n=2:

```
n = 2
arr_multi_dim = results.reshape(nrows, ncols, nrows, ncols)
```

when n=3:

```
n = 3
arr_multi_dim = results.reshape(nrows, ncols, nrows, ncols, nrows, ncols)
```

when n=4:

```
n = 4
arr_multi_dim = results.reshape(nrows, ncols, nrows, ncols, nrows, ncols, nrows, ncols)
```

etc.

where at each increment of `n`, a set of `nrows` and `ncols` gets added into the `reshape()` function.

How do I write a function, loops (or something similar), so that when I specify any values for `n`, the appropriate `reshape()` function will be used?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like task for [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (alias star operator). I would do:

```
arr_multi_dim = results.reshape(*[nrows, ncols]*n)
```

`[nrows, ncols]*2` is turned into `[nrows, ncols, nrows, ncols]`, `[nrows, ncols]*3` is turned into `[nrows, ncols, nrows, ncols, nrows, ncols]` and so on.

Comment: @Leockl note, in this *particular* case the `.reshape` method takes just sequence of dimensions, so you can just pass `results.reshape([nrows, ncols]*n)` without having to splat the arguments

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe?

```
results.reshape(*[nrows,ncol]*n)
```